# Error with HTTP library via the BrowserClient class

Tags: dart

I try to use HTTP [library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http), "Using on the Browser" but get Error in browser console (Dartium) even for example.

Error:
`package:async/src/byte_collector.dart:1 'package:async/src/byte_collector.dart': error: line 42 pos 16: generic functions not supported
T _collectBytes<T>(
               ^: package:async/src/byte_collector.dart`

Downgrade to "0.11.3+2" from "0.11.3+9" helped but I need 0.11.3+9 because of dependence. How to solve the problem with this error?

Comment: What Dart version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using an older Dartium version and need to update to the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you. update to dartium-linux-x64-stable-1.22.1.0 fixed problem.

Comment: Glad to hear :)